# Nomo por skota bovo-specio: "Highland cow"

Tags: single-word-requests

Kio estas la kutima nomo de la jena skota bovo-specio en Esperanto? Mi ne sukcesis trovi ion ajn interrete. Mi kontrolis en Vikipedio, PIV, ReVo kaj la vortaro de John Wells. En la angla oni nomas ĉi tiun beston "Highland cow", en la nederlanda oni diras "Schotse hooglander". Mi improvize uzis la esprimon "skota altlandulo", sed eble ekzistas pli tradicia esprimo.

What is the usual name of the following Scottish cow species in Esperanto? I couldn't find anything online. I checked Wikipedia, PIV, ReVo and John Wells' dictionary. In English this animal is called "Highland cow", in Dutch it's called "Schotse hooglander". I improvisationally used the term "skota altlandulo", but maybe there's a more traditional expression.

[image: Highland cow.]

Comment: "ulo" in "altlandulo" implies it's a person / human. While the English "highlander" and the Dutch "hooglander" can probably refer to either a human or a beast, "ulo" AFAIK cannot be used for non-human animals.

Comment: @das-g While the word "ulo" generally only refers to humans, the suffix "-ul-" is sometimes used to talk about animals. For example: "mamulo", "rampulo", "araneulo", "brankulo". There's a part in PMEG on it: https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ul.html#i-gmp

Comment: Ho, mi ne sciis pri tio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laŭ mia scio, Skota Altlandulo estas la plej senca kaj tute taŭga nomo por tiu besto, kun aliaj alternativoj ekzemple "Skota Altlanda Bovo". Ĝenerale plej gravas ke la uzita esprimo komuniku taŭge la koncepton al la parol-partnero.